# Does broccoli interfere with CYP3A4 metabolism?

Tags: nutrition, drug-metabolism, drug-interactions

There are many articles on the effects of the active ingredients in Broccoli but I have yet to find the "smoking gun" on this question.

I know grapefruit is a big offender in blocking CYP3A4 but I am wondering if broccoli may interfere with CYP3A4.

There are many medications that use this enzyme to metabolize chemicals in today's medicines.
Medicines are very hard on the kidneys so one would naturally want to know if a specific food could be a problem that the individual may consume on a daily basis. What makes me think it could be a problem is this article I have found which I list below:

https://www.intechopen.com/books/drug-discovery/fruit-vegetable-drug-interactions-effects-on-drug-metabolizing-enzymes-and-drug-transporters

Does broccoli interfere with CYP3A4 metabolism?